# Print cmdlet stdout AND assign to variable?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that calls other scripts.  The scripts I call have nice stdout that I want to show but I also need to assign the output to a variable for further processing.  To get the desired effect, I am calling Get-SomeStuff twice.

```
$a = Get-SomeStuff
Get-SomeStuff
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

`Get-SomeStuff | Tee-Object -Variable VarName` should do the trick

`Get-Help -Online Tee-Object` for more information

As per Keith's comments, you will also want to do something like `| Out-Host` or `| Format-Table | Out-Host` so it will get output to the screen instead of the pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can simply dump the contents of the variable afterwards:

```
$a = Get-SomeStuff
$a
```

Comment: Well, I would recommend `$a | Out-Host`, since just $a alone would send it to the default output, usually the pipeline.

Comment: And what do you think Tee-Object does with the output (not the output saved to VarName)?  :-)

Comment: Also the objects stored in $a may need formatting help if output through Write-Host.  You would want to do this: `$a | Out-String | Write-Host`.

Comment: I normally just `Tee` to a file. I guess it's a matter of personal preference. I find the `Tee` command to be more intuitive, especially if I know it's going to be maintained by someone else (or it haunts me in 6 months)